# How to process dataframe for ML using Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I am doing GBT modelling in using pyspark.
I have a dataframe, the features for input (X) are multiple columns: A,B,C
the output (Y) is one column with binary values 0 and 1.

I am confused with the `VectorAssembler` and transform in processing the dataframe for GBT modelling. How could I do it using pyspark?

The code I used in python is like this:

```
X_train, X_test = df_train.select(features), df_test.select(features) #5083, 1133
y_train, y_test = df_train.select(label), df_test.select(label)

gbt = GBTClassifier(maxIter=5, maxDepth=2, labelCol="indexed", seed=42)
model = gbt.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

How could I get the X_train and y_train using pyspark?

Comment: From your code it looks like the features are in a single column (`features`), is this not the case?

Comment: So you are trying to convert scikit-learn code in pyspark ? Did you read spark ml documentation ? It's straightforward concerning things like this?

Answer (score 0):

`VectorAssembler` accepts two arguments inputcols(cols to be assembled in a vector) and outputcol(name of the output col).
A simple example would be

```
from  pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 0, 3, 0),(4,5,6, 1),(7,8,9, 0)], 
              ["a", "b", "c", 'label'])

vecAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=["a", "b", "c"], outputCol="features")

df_va = vecAssembler.transform(df)
```

The `df_VA` now contains four columns `['a', 'b', 'c', 'label','features']`.
Every row in features column contains a vector with values from columns `['a', 'b', 'c']`

The GBTClassifier needs to know which columns is the dependent variable.
So for this dataframe it would be 'label'.
select features and label  columns from df_va and fit your model like this.

```
df_gbt = df_va['label', 'features']
gbt = GBTClassifier(maxIter=5, maxDepth=2, labelCol="label", seed=42)
gbt.fit(df_gbt)
```